# Plot different distributions over histogram with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, curve, density-plot

I was trying to plot a histogram in R and overlay it with densities from different distributions. It worked well for the regular histogram, but I can't get it to work with the ggplot2 package.

```
a <- dataset$age
```

Now follows the code for my regular histogram:

```
Histogram_for_age <- hist(a, prob=T, xlim=c(0,80), ylim=c(0,0.055), main="Histogram for age with density lines", xlab="age") 

mean <- mean(a)
sd <- sd(a)
```

And now the lines/curves for the densities:

```
lines(density(dataset$age), col="blue", lwd=2, lty=1)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean, sd = sd), add = T, col="red", lwd=2, lty=2)
curve(dgamma(x, shape =mean^2/sd^2, scale = sd^2/mean), add = T, col="goldenrod", lwd=2, lty=3)
```

and a legend:

```
legend("topright", 
    c("actual distribution of age","gaussian distribution", "gamma distribution"),  
   lty=c(1,2,3),  
   lwd=c(2,2,2),col=c("blue","red","goldenrod"), cex=0.65)
```

This is what I tried with ggplot2 so far:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=age)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
             colour="black", fill="white") +
geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="lightblue") + stat_function(fun = dgamma, shape=shape)
```

What ggplot2 argument is equivalent to my lines() and curve() arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `stat_density` instead of `geom_density` like this:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=age)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white") +
  stat_density(colour="blue", geom="line", position="identity") +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter), sd=sd(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter))) + 
  stat_function(fun=dgamma, args=list(shape=mean(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter)^2/sd(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter)^2, scale=sd(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter)^2/mean(dataset_with_victims$TV_Alter)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! What do I use for the shape argument regarding my gamma specifications above?

Comment: You probably have to add `geom="point"` and then define the shape. Could you provide some [example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? That makes it a lot easier for me to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Cajira probably meant the `shape` argument in function `dgamma`. You should add `arg=list(shape=...)` to the call of `stat_function()`

Comment: @ilir thanx, I included it in my answer

Comment: Thank you!!! :) I now still have problems. Using your code above, R returns the following:    `stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this`.